# How can I perform a graphLookUp excluding null connections?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to perform a graphLookUp on a nullable field. In this example, I have a collection of "nodes" where both "name" and "connectsTo" may be null, but if they are both null, then this should not be treated as a valid connection:

```
{ _id: 1, name: "1", connectsTo: null }
{ _id: 2, name: "2", connectsTo: "1" }
{ _id: 3, name: "3", connectsTo: "2" }
{ _id: 4, name: null, connectsTo: "3" }
{ _id: 5, name: null, connectsTo: "3" }
{ _id: 6, name: "6", connectsTo: null }
{ _id: 7, name: null, connectsTo: "6" }
```

So the graph looks like this:

```
1 <- 2 <- 3 <- 4
            <- 5
6 <- 7
```

4, 5 and 7 all have null names

I want to get the hierarchy of nodes, from 1 and exclude any nodes disconnected from 1.

I've tried this query:

```
db.nodes.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 1 } },
  { $graphLookup: {
      from: "nodes",
      startWith: "$name",
      connectFromField: "name",
      connectToField: "connectsTo",
      as: "hierarchy",
      depthField: "depth"
  }}
]).pretty()
```

However, this gives the following result:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "1",
    "connectsTo" : null,
    "hierarchy" : [
        { "_id" : 7, "name" : null, "connectsTo" : "6",  "depth" : NumberLong(4) },
        { "_id" : 1, "name" : "1",  "connectsTo" : null, "depth" : NumberLong(3) },
        { "_id" : 6, "name" : "6",  "connectsTo" : null, "depth" : NumberLong(3) },
        { "_id" : 5, "name" : null, "connectsTo" : "3",  "depth" : NumberLong(2) },
        { "_id" : 4, "name" : null, "connectsTo" : "3",  "depth" : NumberLong(2) },
        { "_id" : 3, "name" : "3",  "connectsTo" : "2",  "depth" : NumberLong(1) },
        { "_id" : 2, "name" : "2",  "connectsTo" : "1",  "depth" : NumberLong(0) }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, both 7 and 6 are present. What I suspect is happening is that the null connectsTo of 6 is getting matched against the null name of either 4 or 5.

How can I terminate the hierarchy immediately after nodes with a name of null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use `restrictSearchWithMatch` and exclude where `connectsTo` is not null. Since this terminates the recursion as soon as it matches the node, this excludes 6 (which has a null connectsTo) and then also excludes 7 because 7 is now disconnected from the graph:

```
db.nodes.aggregate([
  { $match: { _id: 1 } },
  { $graphLookup: {
      from: "nodes",
      startWith: "$name",
      connectFromField: "name",
      connectToField: "connectsTo",
      as: "hierarchy",
      depthField: "depth"
      restrictSearchWithMatch: {
        connectsTo: { $ne: null }
      }
  }}
]).pretty()
```